# Is 55 minutes connection in WAW possible?

Tags: short-connections, waw

I have a flight booked from Rzeszow to London with a connection in Warsaw, it's one booking booked on LOT directly and it's not a self-transfer. The connection in WAW is for 55 minutes. It's from domestic to international so will need to go through passport control but no security.

Is 55 minutes possible? I'm not too worried as the flight from WAW to LHR was delayed every day in the last few days by 15 minutes+ and the flight from RZE to WAW arrived earlier than schedule every day in the last few days. But in general is this connection in WAW tight? Looking on WAW maps it seems to be relatively a small airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be fine. Minimum connection time intra Schengen in Warsaw is 35 minutes. I could not find any published times for Schengen to international, but unless Passport control is backed up badly, that should work ok.

Of course, connections are never 100% sure, so there is no harm to research a "plan B". If you miss it, LOT will rebook you on the next available flight to London. If you already know what these are and what options are acceptable to you, you have an easier time negotiating with a gate agent.